# Angular 4 material: md-slider not smoothly slide

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I use material design on an angular 4 application (generated with angular-cli). More precisely, I use a md-slider.

This works almost correctly... The only problem is that, when the user tries to slide the cursor, the cursor don't move before the user release the button of the mouse...

Here a plunker where the problem appears (created from a basis angular 4 plunker, I added material and cdk by hand):
http://embed.plnkr.co/3s5K6U1YEsuTmO0q4aFt

Here an other plunker without the problem (created from a plunker that already implements material and cdk):
http://embed.plnkr.co/KHho3wSZGxAuEJdOwxz1
(the original plunker is the o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd. I have not enough reputation to publish more than two links.)

I can't figure what are the differences between this two plunkers...

Here are the versions of the packages that I use on my local project:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
node: 6.11.2
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/common: 4.3.3
@angular/compiler: 4.3.3
@angular/core: 4.3.3
@angular/forms: 4.3.3
@angular/http: 4.3.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.3
@angular/router: 4.3.3
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.3
@angular/language-service: 4.3.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `hammer.js` reference, which makes the sliding behaviour

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"
```

Refer to this script in your `index.html`. This will fix your issue

Source : The documentation has the below point

[image]

Comment: Indeed! Thank you!

Comment: I have hammer installed, but the sliding behavior still refuses to work. I thought hammer was related to touch events and touch-screen devices. Why is it relevant/necessary in a browser scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You already have an answer but another solution is to add hammerjs to package.json:

> npm --save install hammerjs

And in polyfill.ts add:

```
import 'hammerjs';
```